# OrderBy is broken when trying to update more than one attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In models factory when it is updated only one attribute after succeed put than orderBy in view is working correctly, when trying to update more then one attribute than orderBy is broken, how to update more than one attribute after put success?

```
o.vote = function(post) {
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post.id + '/upvote').success(function(data) {
        post.points = data.points;
        // post.votes = data.votes;
    });
}
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-points'">
```

Comment: where are you getting the points from?

Comment: I've updated my question, also from server response.

Comment: Can you try to replicate it here? http://plnkr.co/edit/h0LwvqJdrCuU4m1cSJCo?p=info

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/tD1AC5Uyyi8s6UZK2rjU?p=preview

Comment: I haven't $scope in factory, it seems that sortBy is working when I click double time, on second $html.put response if I'm updating tow values, when one it sort on first time, so I'll investigate why.